# FFmpeg upscale and downscale a video at once

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Is it possible to upscale a 720p video to 2160p and downscale to 1080p, all in one command?

`Input -> filter -> keep input -> another filter -> output` ?

I know how to do it with two commands, but it doesn't work if I put it in one command.

Comment: May I ask what's the point?

Comment: I'm testing different ways of upscaling and downscaling. I figured it out already. It's `-vf "[0:v]scale=-1:2160[mid];[mid]scale=-1:1080:flags=spline[out]"`

Comment: Actually I tried to pixelate the video, so I downscaled it to `160:90` and upscaled to `1920:1080` using `neighbor` alg. It's time saving

Comment: Congratulations on solving this problem yourself. You can post you solution as an answer and accept it in 48 hours, I believe. The question will then be marked as answered and easier to find for other users.

Comment: Since it's a filterchain working on a single input, you can skip the pads: `-vf "scale=-1:2160,scale=-1:1080:flags=spline"`